# Encrypting and decrypted data before save in cakephp

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, datatables, cakephp-2.3

I am creating a health clinic and portal application in cakephp. I need to insert encrypted data in database not using base64 encode and decode method and to use in search also. Can someone help me by providing their valuable suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and question advice (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question omits pretty much everything we need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Cookbook under Models > Callback Methods. 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html

Maybe you need to use beforeSave and afterFind?

You could use beforeSave to encrypt data before it hits the database, and afterFind to decrypt it between the database and controller.

Comment: I want to know which method to use to encrypt and decrypt data and save encrypt data in database except base64encode or decode method

Comment: That's not something I'm familliar with. Maybe ask a question about PHP encryption, rather than Cake and SQL, then integrate that solution with this one.